# How to fix utf8 in terminal?

Tags: command-line, encoding, utf-8

I have a fresh installation of Xenial server inside a Virtualbox. While installing, I chose “No Localisation” and “C” as the default language. Now `less` thinks every file with non-Latin alphabet is a binary one, and the terminal won't display non-Latin characters correctly.

What I tried is uncommenting a line in `/etc/locale.gen` and re-running `sudo locale-gen`. I also tried installing `language-support-*` and reconfiguring package `locales`. Even rebooting won't help.

I'm sure this is not about SSH, because I tried typing it in the Vitrualbox window itself as well. `locale` output:

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

The contents of `/etc/default/locale`:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
#LANG="C"
```

The output of `locale-gen`:

```
$ sudo locale-gen 
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_AG.UTF-8... done
  en_AU.UTF-8... done
  en_BW.UTF-8... done
  en_CA.UTF-8... done
  en_DK.UTF-8... done
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
  en_HK.UTF-8... done
  en_IE.UTF-8... done
  en_IN.UTF-8... done
  en_NG.UTF-8... done
  en_NZ.UTF-8... done
  en_PH.UTF-8... done
  en_SG.UTF-8... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
  en_ZA.UTF-8... done
  en_ZM.UTF-8... done
  en_ZW.UTF-8... done
  ru_RU.UTF-8... done
  ru_UA.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

The problem:

```
$ LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8 date
(outputs gibberish)

$ file -i README.md
README.md: text/plain; charset=utf-8

$ less README.md
"README.md" may be a binary file. See it anyway?
```

Is there a way to fix it without reinstalling?